# vite react typescript - tsconfig moduleResolution makes VSCode intellisense loading forever

Tags: reactjs, typescript, intellisense, vite

I'm new to JS world. Please let me know the correct way and where did I go wrong. Thank you so much!

My project use `Vite^4.3.2`, `React^18.2.0` & `Typescript^5.0.4`. I have to use an specific external react components library with `pnpm v7.14.0` and `node v16.20.0` (project specs required that).

---

**The problem**: Typescript and vscode's intellisense can't detect the props type of components from that lib: [Alway show `any`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LhVfI.png), so I don't know what props the component has and the types of each. The intellisense work as expected with other libraries such as `formik`, `dayjs`, `react-router-dom`, it shows type correctly.

There are no ESlint error. I checked `pnpm dev` or build production then preview it, my app functions work fine on both env.

---

My `tsconfig.json` file is basically the same as the default created by Vite:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ESNext",
    "lib": ["DOM", "DOM.Iterable", "ESNext"],
    "module": "ESNext",
    "skipLibCheck": true,

    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "~/*": ["./src/*"]
    },

    /* Bundler mode */
    "moduleResolution": "bundler",
    "allowImportingTsExtensions": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",

    /* Linting */
    "strict": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true
  },
  "include": ["./src"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"],
  "references": [{ "path": "./tsconfig.node.json" }]
}
```

`tsconfig.node.json`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "composite": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "module": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "bundler",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
  },
  "include": ["vite.config.ts"]
}
```

`vite.config.ts`

```
import {defineConfig} from 'vite';
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react-swc';
// import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react';
import tsconfigPaths from 'vite-tsconfig-paths';
import svgr from 'vite-plugin-svgr';

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react(), tsconfigPaths(), svgr()],
  server: {
    open: true,
  },
  build: {
    commonjsOptions: {
      ignoreTryCatch: false,
    },
  },
});
```

---

I have no idea how to make intellisense can detect the props of components like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3E7PZ.png)

So i tried to change `moduleResolution` to `node` and add `"allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true` to `tsconfig.json` then restart vscode. But
[vscode intellisense loading forever](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mKEKf.png) only on this project.

[Typescript of my workspace and VSCode are the same version `5.0.4`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/38543.png)

---

**Additional info:**

Env: Windows 11 - 22H2, `nodejs` v16.20.0, `pnpm` v7.14.0, VSCode v1.78.2 (user setup), .

This is declare from node_modules
[Component of external lib](https://i.stack.imgur.com/meyAP.png)

That @stitches... is
[already on `node_modules/.pnpm`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P7YAC.png)

Comment: Did you find any solution? I am facing same issues!

Comment: I know this is a really old issue, but I've managed to solve it by changing the `moduleResolution` to `node` in my tsconfig. I'm still doing research as to why this happens.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you are using the old version of VSCode, update your VSCode and the error will go away.